# Undestanding events and listeners in Java

Tags: java, events

JDK provides with some basic events specification:

- `EventObject` is a standard JDK [EventObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html).
- `EventListnere` tagging [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html)

Since `EventListener` is written as follows:

```
public interface EventListener {
}
```

any time I need to provide a facility of handling events I need to extend it with my own interface containing a method like `handleEvent(EventObject o)`. To me it's not clear why the JDK's `EventListener` interface is empty, because I think it doesn't make too much sense to have events without a facility of handling them.

What did I miss in the event model? Maybe there were actually some reasons for leaving it empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventListener` is a tagging interface. Its subinterfaces such as `ActionListener` define more useful methods.

Since they're JDK1.1 classes, there's a good chance that they weren't that well thought out and can seem bizarre in modern Java.

Comment: Actually, I see. But they are the part of a specific frameworks (e.g. `java.awt.ActionListener`). So the main purpose of this interface is to provide flexibility of the name of "handling methods"?

Comment: _can seem bizarre in modern Java_ You personally would not use it in production code, wouldn't you?